# How to add JSONarray to arraylist in android

Tags: android, arraylist

Trying to add 5 JSONarrays to arraylist but getting this error

```
The method add(AllMessageObject) in the type ArrayList<AllMessageObject> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

Here i am placing code to add jsonarray to arraylist.how to fix it.

```
for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
listdata  = new ArrayList<AllMessageObject>();

listdata.add(jsonArray.get(j).toString());
```

}

AllMessageObject is a class here is my code to that class.and listdata is my array list `ArrayList<AllMessageObject> listdata = null;`
i hope this code is sufficient ,if you need more i'll provide it here.

```
public class AllMessageObject {

// for getting comment
public String message;
public String from_name;
public String message_date;

// for getting picture 
public String picture_url;
public Bitmap picturein_bitmap;

// for getting my profile image
public String fromprofile_url;
//public Bitmap fromprofileurl_bitmap;


public String getFromprofile_url() {
    return fromprofile_url;
}
public void setFromprofile_url(String fromprofile_url) {
    this.fromprofile_url = fromprofile_url;
}
/*public Bitmap getFromprofileurl_bitmap() {
    return fromprofileurl_bitmap;
}
public void setFromprofileurl_bitmap(Bitmap fromprofileurl_bitmap) {
    this.fromprofileurl_bitmap = fromprofileurl_bitmap;
}*/
public Bitmap getPicturein_bitmap() {
    return picturein_bitmap;
}
public void setPicturein_bitmap(Bitmap picturein_bitmap) {
    this.picturein_bitmap = picturein_bitmap;
}
public String getPicture_url() {
    return picture_url;
}
public void setPicture_url(String picture_url) {
    this.picture_url = picture_url;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public String getFrom_name() {
    return from_name;
}
public void setFrom_name(String from_name) {
    this.from_name = from_name;
}
public String getMessage_date() {
    return message_date;
}
public void setMessage_date(String message_date) {
    this.message_date = message_date;
}



}
```

Comment: please put entire code. Your problem is not clear. What is AllMessageObject?? is it class??

Comment: As the error states, you have an ArrayList of AllMessageObject, but are trying to put inside it a String

Comment: are you trying to set value for message of AllMessageObject?

Comment: @blackbelt i got it,but how to fix it?

Comment: learn how to parse a json as first thing

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put `String` inside an `AllMessageObject` ArrayList. Also you allocate new `ArrayList` each time your loop runs you will loose the previously added values.

So instead try like this:

```
listdata  = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {   
    listdata.add(jsonArray.get(j).toString());
}
```